# jOOQ depends on unstable version of r2dbc-spi library

Tags: java, jooq, r2dbc

Current jOOQ version 3.15.4 in [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jooq/jooq/3.15.4) depends on unstable version `0.9.0.M1` of `r2dbc-spi` (Not even the latest milestone release). We have a strong policy not allowing unstable libraries in production, so we can’t use the latest jOOQ version.

Is it ok rewrite the dependency and downgrade `r2dbc-spi` to `0.8.6` (latest stable but still not `1.x`)?

Comment: FWIW, you can wait a few days (Dec 6 to be precise) until R2DBC 0.9 GA is released, see https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-spi/milestone/19.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few good reasons why a `0.9.x` dependency was added to jOOQ 3.15 instead of a `0.8.x`, despite the milestone / release candidate suffixes:

#### 1. R2DBC SPI stability

The R2DBC SPI is not too stable yet, in general. The `0.x` version scheme hints at things still being "in motion", and backwards incompatible SPI changes still being implemented. jOOQ (i.e. me) has been involved quite a bit in the recent design decisions of the SPI to make sure the usual requirements known to jOOQ will be addressed correctly. These include the requirements of streaming operations when calling stored procedures in SQL Server or MySQL, [where result sets, exceptions, and update counts can be interleaved](https://blog.jooq.org/how-i-incorrectly-fetched-jdbc-resultsets-again/), or also how out parameters are streamed.

As such, to jOOQ, it doesn't seem too important whether a release is tagged as a "milestone", "release candidate", or a "stable" release, given that even after a stable release, there will be breaking SPI changes.

#### 2. jOOQ is hiding R2DBC from you

For you, this may or may not matter too much. While I understand your dependency version policy in general, in this particular case, you're using beta software (R2DBC), which is a risk on its own. jOOQ will try to shield you from any instabilities, because you will hardly ever see R2DBC API in your client code (much like you hardly ever see JDBC API in your client code), and the status quo is well integration tested to make sure jOOQ code works correctly.

From your application perspective, jOOQ is just a reactive streams implementation, and it could switch R2DBC for something else at any time. In fact, it already does. You can use it as a "blocking stream" on top of JDBC as well.

#### 3. jOOQ dependency on new R2DBC SPI features and fixes

When R2DBC was supported in jOOQ 3.15, it seemed useful to already depend on the latest implementation of the SPI and its drivers to get a better experience in the details of jOOQ's internals. In fact, binding to them already now helped improve them and find some usability issues, such as this [batching specification problem](https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-spi/issues/229), which hadn't been specified explicitly, and thus implemented differently on a per driver basis.

Also, some driver bug fixes couldn't be addressed without addressing flaws in the SPI, so they weren't backported to 0.8.6.

#### Your question

jOOQ doesn't integration test version `0.8` of the SPI and of the R2DBC drivers, so whether this downgrade is OK for you is up to you to find out. If you find a problem in jOOQ with R2DBC `0.8` that wouldn't happen with `0.9`, then that issue will probably not be addressed by jOOQ.

So, while your policy would be fulfilled, your quality may still suffer. I recommend you adapt your policy in this particular case, at least for as long as you use R2DBC as a transitive dependency of jOOQ, and not a direct one.

Regarding:

> Not even the latest milestone release

At the time of the release, the drivers weren't ready for the latest SPI milestone release. This is still the case now, when we're planning to upgrade the SPI dependency to a release candidate or something even newer: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12193.

Such is life when working with new things like R2DBC. It works decently well, but things are still unstable, behind the scenes. Knowing that things will stabilise eventually, you can already work with the status quo.

#### More resources:

- The jOOQ 3.15 R2DBC support ticket: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11700
- The jOOQ 3.16 R2DBC known limitation ticket: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11717
- The jOOQ 3.16 dependency upgrade ticket: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12193
- Various discussions on the R2DBC mailing list: https://groups.google.com/g/r2dbc